# How to handle jQuery UISlider change event for range slider

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, slider, jquery-ui-slider, rangeslider

I have a two handle jQuery UI Slider, under each handle of it, there's a number that should change everytime user changes the handles, I can only change one of them.

I need to detect which handle has been moved, and in which direction it has moved, to calculate the numbers.

HTML:

```
<div id="slider-range"></div>
<div id="amount">
    <span class="minslider"><span class="minprice">0</span> Dollar</span>
    <span class="maxslider"><span class="maxprice">3000000</span> Dollar</span>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
 $(function() {
    $( "#slider-range" ).slider({
        range: true,
        min: 0,
        max: 15,
        values: [ 0, 15 ],
        step: 1,
        change: function( event, ui ) {
            var maxprice = $('.maxprice').text();
            var oneslice = Math.round(maxprice / 15);
            var finalprice = maxprice - oneslice;
            $('.maxprice').text(finalprice);
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: Didn't this example helped you ? http://jqueryui.com/slider/#range